Finding parameter for positive semi-definiteness in the sum of two quadratic forms
here's a problem I've come across. It involves determining the values of a parameter $t$ for which a quadratic form $h$ is positive semi-definite.
I've briefly discussed this with some friends, and opinions vary. Some believe the form is never positive or positive semi-definite, while others have proposed different ranges for $t$. ChatGPT also seems to offer contradictory solutions, using Sylvester's criterion or eigenvalue criterion.
Any insights or step-by-step methods you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Problem
Consider the two quadratic forms given by
$$f(x_1,x_2)=-16x_1^2+8x_1x_2-2x_2^2$$
and
$$g(x_1,x_2)=-4x_1x_2.$$
We want to determine for which values of $t$ the quadratic form $h(x_1,x_2)$ is positive semi-definite.
$$h(x_1,x_2)=(1-t)f(x_1,x_2)+tg(x_1,x_2).$$
